# DataBinding a ComboBox's SelectedValue in WinRT Prism/MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox, windows-runtime

I am having an issue with trying to bind a `ComboBox` in WinRT.  I am using Prism/MVVM.  I am able to bind the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection` no problem, and the `ComboBox` is being populated.

What I am having trouble with, is having it automatically select the appropriate value based on the current `Invoice`.  Here is the relevant XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Payees}"
          DisplayMemberPath="AccountName"
          SelectedValuePath="PayeeId"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentInvoice.PayeeId, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

`Payees` is my `ObservableCollection` and `CurrentInvoice` is a property on the `ViewModel` that points to the currently loaded `Invoice` item.  The `Invoice` has a property called `PayeeId`, which as you may guess, is the `Id` of the `Payee` that this `Invoice` is associated to.

For some reason, no matter which `Invoice` I select, the `ComboBox` is blank when I navigate to my page.  By blank, I just mean there is nothing selected, but it is populated with the `Payees` collection.

If I manually change the selection, and save my `Invoice`, the `PayeeId` isn't changed.  I think that it probably has something to do with the binding on the `SelectedValue`, but so far I have been unable to figure this one out.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Here are the properties for the `Payees` and `CurrentInvoice`:

```
private Invoice _currentInvoice;
public Invoice CurrentInvoice {
    get { return _currentInvoice; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _currentInvoice, value); } 
}

private ObservableCollection<Payee> _payees;
public ObservableCollection<Payee> Payees
{
    get { return _payees; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _payees, value); }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have added a property on the `ViewModel` called `SelectedPayee` that is bound to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`.  Here is the updated definition:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Payees}"
          DisplayMemberPath="AccountName"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPayee, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

When I select a `Payee` and save, it saves with the new `PayeeId`, but when I load the page it still does not load with the `SelectedPayee` displayed in the `ComboBox`.  However, all is well in the designer.  To further test, I have added a `TextBox` that is bound to `SelectedPayee.Id`:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPayee.Id}" />
```

That displayed the correct number at design time and runtime, and is updated appropriately whenever I change the selection in the `ComboBox`.  The only thing that is not working correctly is the `ComboBox` is not correctly displaying the `Payee` `AccountName` when I navigate to the page.  As I said, the design view is correctly displaying the dummy data that I have in my designer `ViewModel`.  Is there something special about a `ComboBox` that I am perhaps doing something in the wrong order?

**EDIT 2:**

I also am getting the exact same results using

```
SelectedValue={Binding Path=SelectedPayee.Id, Mode=TwoWay}
```

The binding is displaying the correct `Payee.Id` in the `TextBox` depending on which `Payee` is selected in the `ComboBox`, but it just does not display the `SelectedPayee` when I first navigate to the page (but the `TextBox` will be populated with the correct `Id`.)  This is really a head scratcher to me....

**EDIT 3:**

I got it all straightened out.  The final issue I had going was I was setting the `SelectedPayee` before actually loading the `ComboBox`, so there was no property changes to trigger the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` to change.  Once I moved the call to `LoadPayees()` above the assignment to `SelectedValue`, everything works like a charm.  **See answer below.**

Comment: I dont know how exactly this component works, but usually the selected in combobox means index, not concrete value. Also if you try to hardcode selectedValue into combobox, does it works as expected?

Comment: There are `SelectedIndex` as well as `SelectedValue` properties on a `ComboBox`.  The `SelectedValue` should be a `PayeeId` as it shows in the XAML, rather than an index of an item.

Comment: Hmm, what about `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentInvoice.PayeeId, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: I would try removing use of the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath and instead use the SelectedItem.

Comment: @libik I'm not sure what you mean by the last comment "SelectedValue=...", that is what I have already (`Path=` is implied).  I have tried both ways and same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question looking for a solution, what I ended up finding out was that I was setting the `SelectedPayee` *before* loading the `ComboBox`.  I moved the call to `LoadPayees()` up above the `SelectedPayee` assignment, and now everything works as expected!  Here is my `OnNavigatedTo()` method for anyone interested:

```
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(object navigationParameter, NavigationMode navigationMode,
    Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
{
    _headerViewModel.PageTitle = "Invoice Details";

    await LoadPayees();
    if (navigationParameter is Invoice)
    {
        _isEditing = true;
        CurrentInvoice = navigationParameter as Invoice;

        var payee = await _payeesRepository.LoadByIdAsync(CurrentInvoice.PayeeId);
        SelectedPayee = payee;

        await LoadPayments();
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInvoice = new Invoice
        {
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
            InvoiceDate = DateTime.Now,
            Frequency = "M"
        };
    }
    /* await LoadPayees(); was originally down here... oops! */

    base.OnNavigatedTo(navigationParameter, navigationMode, viewModelState);
}
```